Visual bug on second monitor after installing nvidia driver 560
I'm using Debian12 / BookWorm.
I tried installing the nvidia CUDA Toolkit, which apparently installed different drivers (I think). IIRC I had the 535 Driver, now I have the 560 driver.
My second monitor has been visually glitchy since the 560 driver.
My PC has a Nvidia 3060 TI
My desktop Environment (from Screenfetch): KDE 5.103.0 / Plasma 5.27.5
I want to fix the visual glitches on my second monitor. If that's not possible, I want to go back to having the 535 Driver, or whichever drive that was. I simply ran sudo nvidia-detect sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver once a day ago and that went fine.
Things I've tried:
To delete formerly installed nvidia packages:
sudo apt purge nivida.

I've also manually deleted packages listed under dpkg -i | grep nvidia-driver after this, until there was no packages listed under that anymore. There were still some packages listed under dpkg -i | grep nvidia after these steps, not sure if that's supposed to be.
then:
sudo apt-get install nvidia-detect
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver

but this installed nvidia-driver-560 again, even though when I ran it with the 535 driver it didn't do anything IIRC.
